# Script gives a curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL only on CentOS

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a script below. every time i run it on my Linux (CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)), I get this error: `curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL`

I installed ""Windows Subsystem for Linux" (Ubuntu) and ran the same script on it, and it was executed successfully.

Does anyone know what the reason could be?

---

```
token="SEC: xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"
addurl="https://10.10.10.99/api/reference_data/sets/testset?value="

for a in $(cat test_List.csv); do
    addcontent="$(curl -X POST -k -H "$token" "$addurl$a")"
    echo "$addcontent"
done
```

Comment: Use -d to pass value parameters, not just append to URL.

Comment: Strip the carriage returns from your csv files